# Open notepad.exe in VisualBasic and set visibility to false?

Tags: vb.net, notepad

I am looking to open new .txt files in a program but I need to have an instance of notepad open first. I would like to have notepad not visible. Is it possible to do this? I am currently using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe", filename)
```

where filename is the path of the file I want to open.

Comment: Why would you want to open an invisible notepad in the first place? Why not just manipulate your text file through visual basic code?

Comment: @Banana I am trying to rewrite the text from a csv file to a txt file because of some encoding errors on my exported csv file.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry about that! I will change it. Thanks!

Comment: It can all be done via vb code, you dont need to call and manage other programs for it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Banana. I am trying to open up a notepad instance and then save the csv file as a .txt file. I have tried to do this within my vb code but it still wasn't working with the rest of my code after the fact, hence why I think some type of format conversion is happening on the open/save/close portion. 

Is there another way that you would suggest? I am open to suggestions but I have already tried it that way :)

Comment: Notepad is one way of viewing and manipulating text files (.txt). In your program, you should only worry about creating a file. If you're seeing a different format than you expect in your text file when you open it up in notepad, you probably need to look at other things like codepage or Unicode/ascii, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend calling other apps for simple text conversions, it's really a bad idea especially if you are turning them invisible. You wouldn't want to get stuck with countless invisible notepad instances if you forget to terminate them properly. If its a conversion issue it can always be fixed in code. I suggest researching about the specific issue that you are experiencing. Also look into mime types, might lead you to what you need.

Comment: Also, don't overlook the possibility that your code might be adding or removing things along the line.

Comment: @WillMiller, is that how you would rename a file in windows explorer? would you open it in notepad and then save it with a different filename? of course you would not.  .... just rename the file without opening it.